# Use multiple profile on EC2 instance without any credentials

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have an EC2 instance assigned to an IAM role giving it permissions to access some AWS services (the most important is SecretsManager).

It works pretty good but now we want to access the same services in a more secured way by segmenting access.

So on the same EC2 instance access 2 different secrets. I'm pretty sure that we can achieve this using the `aws --profile [PROFILE_NAME]` command, but I haven't manage to properly configure this (and also if it's the right way to do this).

I don't think it's possible to assign multiple roles to an EC2 instance, so I assume I have to configure a single role with policies that grant all segment access. And then find a way to use this role to use the services in a secure way.

**EDIT :**

My role gives access to the Secrets Manager service and several secrets. When assigning this role to my EC2 instance I can access to every secrets described without specifying any profile. My goal would be to be able to access a secret per profile (and none using default).

Is it something even feasible, and if yes how ?

Comment: Yes, you cannot have instance roles / instance profiles. Use one role. There is little / no reason to use multiple.

Comment: It is not possible to have multiple roles assigned to the same instance. You can configure multiple profile if you want, however, I'm not sure, based on your description, if that would be the best thing to do since you can easily switch from one profile to another. So it means at then end, having the same permission as if you would add it to your existing role...

Comment: Configuring cli profiles on the EC2 instance is explicitly discouraged.

Comment: Alright I as thought, using a single role is the right thing to do here. It's not really important that we can switch from one profile to another, the aws CLI commands will be froze and variabilized so it's fine for us. The thing is that I can't manage to use one or many profiles using a role. I'm updating the question with more informations

Comment: Why do you want to have to specify a profile?

Comment: My objective is that when doing a aws CLI command from my EC2 instance without any profile I should not be able to reach any service. So it seems that define a profile for each segmentation could work. Again this is just an idea, maybe there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Any update on last question ?